# How to Display Sharepoint List item by selecting id of list item using list web services?

Tags: web-services

How to Display SharePoint list item by selecting id of the item by using list web services (lists.asmx).

Comment: using C# client object model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code.

Change the ID in CAML query according to your needs. I am using get me item whose ID=1

```
public void getListData()
        {
            WS_Lists.Lists myservice = new WS_Lists.Lists();
            myservice.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            myservice.Url = "http://site/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
            try
            {
                /* Assign values to pass the GetListItems method*/
                string listName = "ListName";
                string viewName = "ViewName";
                string rowLimit = "1";

                // Instantiate an XmlDocument object
                System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
                System.Xml.XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
                System.Xml.XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");

                /*Use CAML query*/
                query.InnerXml = "<Where><eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />" +
                "<Value Type=\"Counter\">1</Value></eq></Where>";
                viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />";
                queryOptions.InnerXml = "";

                System.Xml.XmlNode nodes = myservice.GetListItems(listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, null, null);

                foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in nodes)
                {
                    if (node.Name == "rs:data")
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "z:row")
                            {
                                Response.Write(node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_Title"].Value + "</br>");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it's working. And thanks is nothing without an UpVote :)